# How is this Regex interpreted?

Tags: regex, express

I'm a little confused about the example on this page: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

> ```
> This route path will match abcd, abxcd, abRANDOMcd, ab123cd, and so on.
>
>
> app.get('/ab*cd', function(req, res) {
>   res.send('ab*cd');
> });
> ```

After typing this example into here: http://regexr.com/

I can't recreate the same behaviour and match abxyzcd.

Why is this and what is the difference in the regex and the way it is interpreted?

Comment: Something strange there.  The descriptions of the other examples look okay, but that isn't how the star works in regexes.  `ab*cd` should match `acd`, `abcd`, `abbcd`, etc., but **not** `abxcd`, `abRANDOMcd` or `ab123cd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you got there, isn't Regex, but a string containing a wildcard. My regex isn't very good, but I believe the `*` is interpreted the same way as `.*` in regex.

As it says in the link you supplied:

> Here are some examples of route paths based on strings.

While further down you see:

> Examples of route paths based on regular expressions:

So there is basically two ways to create patterns in your routes :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the ExpressJS syntax is different than standard RegEx syntax.

**This is the RegEx version of that pattern:**

[image: Lazy]

**If you don't use the lazy modifier ( "`?`" ), you will get this result:**

[image: Non-Lazy]

I recommend looking into the ExpressJS syntax further to find out how they differentiate lazy & non-lazy searching.

Answer (score 1):

In normal regular expresions * means that the preceding character can be matched 0 or more times, so with the regex you gave, you could match abbcd and abbbbcd etc.

If you want to match abrandomcd you could use the regex `ab.*cd`
The . means match any character, and the star means match any number of them.

As far as I can tell the example on that expressjs page is using a different form of regular expression than regexr or another normal engine would.

This is highlighted in the text

> The characters ?, +, *, and () are subsets of their regular expression
>   counterparts. The hyphen (-) and the dot (.) are interpreted literally
>   by string-based paths.

Found on the page.